# Borel Cantelli conceptual problem

Tags: probability, paradox

I recently learned about the Borel-Cantelli lemmas and although I could follow the derivation and it seems watertight, I have a problem wrapping my head around its implication. I hope you can tell me where the error in my train-of-thought is.

Let us take as an example a coin-toss experiment with $\mathbb{P}(H_{n})=\frac{1}{n^{2}},n\geq1$ the chance of obtaining a head on the $n$th toss. Then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(H_{n})<\infty$. By the first Borell-Cantelli lemma, a.s. only finitely many heads will occur.

Now I struggle with the following paradox:

- On the one hand, Borel-Cantelli tells me that the occurence of heads decreases fast enough that after a some finite $N$, there will be no heads a.s.
- On the other hand, for any given finite $N$, the probability that the next toss will be a head is given by $\mathbb{P}(H_{N+1})=\frac{1}{(N+1)^{2}}$, which is non-zero.

Can you explain where in my reasoning I am making a mistake?

Comment: The $N$ after which no head occurs is itself random.

Comment: To echo that comment: there is a positive chance that your given finite $N$ is *not* greater than the point at which the last head occurs.